# Failed to run the Flutter compiler. Exit code: 127

Tags: flutter

**I had created a new project by this command**

```
flutter create newproject
```

**After creating the project I had fire this command**

```
flutter run
```

**then the output is**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle... 0.6s
Resolving dependencies... 1.0s
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
/home/Flutter/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm-profile/linux-x64/gen_snapshot: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to run the Flutter compiler. Exit code: 127

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script '/home/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 421

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:flutterDependenciesDebug'.

Process 'command '/home/Flutter/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Gradle build failed: 1
```

`

**What went worng, i can't understand**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Are you using the latest Flutter version? `flutter --version` should print `Flutter 0.1.6 ...`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Linux flavours please add lib32 std c++ dependency as mentioned below

```
On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
On Fedora: dnf install libstdc++.i686
On Arch: pacman -S lib32-libstdc++5
```

More details at below flutter github ticket
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15025